# Front page without language prefix

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, redirection

I have a multilingual site on Drupal 8 migrated from Drupal 7. It has URL language detection method. Default language is English, it has path prefix `/en`.

With this configuration front page is displayed by the url: `site.com/en`

Can I somehow remove this prefix **only** on the Frontpage (English) with the 301 redirect from `site.com/en` → `site.com`?

It was possible to do this in Drupal 7. But how it can be done in Drupal 8?

I understand that I can remove the prefix from the default language, but I'm interested in keeping it as it was and change only the front page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can configure it from  " /admin/config/regional/language/detection/url "